# User-friendly wrapper or replacement for `at` command under OS X

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks, cron, launchd, at

I often want my computer to automatically add something to my to-do list at some point in the future. In some cases I want to add the same thing at regular intervals. In these cases I use OS X's `launchd` via [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/). But I don't have a great solution for commands that I only want to run once. Judging by Lingon X, `launchd` is not the answer. When I add a new event, Lingon's options for "When" are

> 1. At startup and when saving
> 2. Always
> 3. Mounting a volume
> 4. Time

and if I select "Time" the options I get are "Every hour," "Every day," etc.

I believe that in principle the `at` command is the answer, BUT:

1. `at` runs on the command line; I'd prefer a GUI. Perhaps someone has written a front-end? I can't find run, but "at" is a common word and so is hard to google for.
2. `atrun` is disabled by default under Mac OS, [apparently because it is power-inefficient](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050921214411382): "at is a cronjob, which by default is scheduled to run every minute. It scans its directory for jobs that have expired and runs them. With 1 disk hit per minute, the drive will not sleep much which causes problems, especially on laptops." For my application the job running 30 minutes late is not a problem so perhaps `atrun` with a longer cycle would work.

What is the preferred way to schedule commands to run only once at some time in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Script Timer](http://www.appsandmore.com/script_timer.htm) seems to be one option. The author writes, "Yes, you can schedule a job to run only once in Script Timer. It is treated as a special case for a repeating job - you just set the repeating time interval to zero."

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule scripts/commands from iCal by creating an event and setting an alarm to "Run Script".

Optionally, if you want to execute some commands regularly - you should really look into using Cronjobs. Cronjobs let you specify command which will be executed at specific time(s).

There are various GUI frontends for managing cronjob on Mac:

- Cronnix - http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/
- Maintidget - http://www.giantmike.com/widgets/Maintidget.html
- Macaroni - http://www.atomicbird.com/macaroni
- MacJanitor - http://personalpages.tds.net/~brian_hill/macjanitor.html

Comment: So you would advise using cronjobs over launchd? In what contexts? On OS X `man crontab` says, "Darwin note: Although cron(8) and crontab(5) are officially supported under Darwin, their functionality has been absorbed into launchd(8), which provides a more flexible way of automatically executing commands." In any case, my question here is how to run jobs on a non-recurring basis; sounds like iCal is a reasonable possibility. Thanks.